# Why should I use CamelCase for namedtuple?

Tags: python, pep8

Assuming this code snippet (ipython)

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple
In [2]: type(namedtuple)
Out[2]: function
```

you can see that factory function `namedtuple` is a `function`, of course. I can't see any hint in PEP-8 to use the naming convention for classes in that case. I can only see that the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) treating it like a class as a naming convention.

Why should one use the naming convention for classes in that case?

Comment: `namedtuple` is a *class factory* - a function that creates and returns a class. What you get back is a class, so should be named in `CamelCase` like any other class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're referring to the use of the name `Point` for the type returned by `namedtuple`. `namedtuple` is a function alright, but it returns a class (a thing that has the type `type`). And by [PEP-8, class names should look LikeThis](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple
In [2]: Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
In [3]: type(Point)
Out[3]: type
```